# from skimage import data

Tags: python, python-import, scikit-image

I am not able to import the data module of scikit-image however it is listed as installed in my conda environment.
The error what I get is the following:

```
>>> from skimage import data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mathegergely/anaconda3/envs/ssVITDino/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skimage/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    from .data import data_dir
  File "/home/mathegergely/anaconda3/envs/ssVITDino/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skimage/data/__init__.py", line 270, in <module>
    _init_pooch()
  File "/home/mathegergely/anaconda3/envs/ssVITDino/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skimage/data/__init__.py", line 256, in _init_pooch
    shutil.copy2(osp.join(skimage_distribution_dir, 'data', 'README.txt'),
  File "/home/mathegergely/anaconda3/envs/ssVITDino/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 444, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/home/mathegergely/anaconda3/envs/ssVITDino/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 387, in copystat
    _copyxattr(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow)
  File "/home/mathegergely/anaconda3/envs/ssVITDino/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 337, in _copyxattr
    os.setxattr(dst, name, value, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/home/mathegergely/.cache/scikit-image/0.18.3/data/README.txt'
```

I do not understand why I get this error message.

Anyone's help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What's in "home/mathegergely/.cache/scikit-image/0.18.3/data/"?

Comment: @randomdatascientist there is just the README.txt file. Nothing else. I already tried to update scikit-image via conda, but it did not help. Scikit-image got updated but the content of the directory were not changed.

Comment: I've had lots of problems using the conda version of scikit-learn. Maybe try making a virtual environment + pip installing scikit-learn + scikit-image? Personally I just pip installed scikit-learn on conda base but the proper way would be to do it in a virtual environment.

Comment: it's installed but there is something weird with the cache directory. I suggest either deleting the directory, making sure to upgrade to the latest version of `pooch`, which is the library that manages our example data, or both. Can you let us know once you've tried that?

Comment: @Juan Non of your suggestions worked for me. I tried to delete the data folder and separately update pooch. Neither resolved my problem.

Comment: Ok, more questions: (a) does that README.txt file exist? Do all the .cache/scikit-image/0.18.3/data folders exist? and (b) if you `ls -l` that directory, what are the permissions on the directory and on the file? Are you running Python with sudo or did you install with sudo? Maybe the file exists but because it was created by sudo you can't overwrite it?

Comment: @Juan To answer part (a): Booth the folder and the file exist. and to further answer part (b): I don't have sudo privileges and `ls -altrh` returns with `-rw-r-----` for the file and with `drwxr-s--x` for the `data` directory.

Comment: That's weird! Is it possible for a non-sudo user to create sudo-only files?

Comment: Put this another way: how did you delete those files if you don't have write access to them?

Comment: @Juan I do not fully understand what you mean under "sudo-only files". In my understanding this directory is under my user `'/home/mathegergely/.cache/scikit-image/0.18.3/data/README.txt'`. Which indicates that I should be able to change or even delete this file or folder. Am I wrong or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Oh oops! No, that's my mistake: I had the permissions backwards in my head!  Anyway, the permissions are like this for me: `-rw-rw-r--  1 jni  staff   280B 24 Aug 21:49 /Users/jni/Library/Caches/scikit-image/0.18.3/data/README.txt` and `drwxr-xr-x  33 jni  staff   1.0K 11 Sep 11:10 data`. So maybe a Python subprocess needs read access to this file/execute access to the folder to work? Can you chmod the files and try again?

Comment: Did you ever try installing a fresh version of scikit-learn with pip? The conda forge version is outdated.